# Show that $ B = \{6k +9 : k ∈ \mathbb Z\} \subset A = \{3l-6 : l \in \mathbb Z\}.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have a problem showing that $B = \{6k +9 : k ∈ \mathbb Z\}   ⊂ A = \{3l-6 : l ∈ \mathbb Z\}$
I think that $B ⊂ A$ is true, because for example $B = \{15, 21 , 27, ...\}$ and $A = \{-3,0,3,6,...,15,...,21,...\}$
So $A$ increments in steps of $3$ and $B$ increments in steps of $6$.
That means all the values of $B$ are also in $A$, so $B ⊂ A$.
I know that I need to show that if $ x ∈ B $ then also $ x ∈ A $ but just cannot figure it out mathematically.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to show that $x\in B$ implies $x\in A$. So let $x\in B$, which means(by the definition of $B$) that
$$x=6k+9$$
From this we get
$$x=6k+15-6=3(2k+5)-6$$
Which is of the form $3l-6$, so by the definition of $A$, $x\in A$. Which further implies $A\subset B$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x\in B$. Then, $x = 6k+9$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now,
$$ x = 6k + 9 = (6k+15)-6 = 3(2k+5)-6\implies x = 3l-6\text{ for some } l\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Thus, $x\in A$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, the desired conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

$$6k+9=3l-6 \iff 3l=6k+15 \iff l=2k+5.$$

Can you proceed ?